# external IP-address in C#

Tags: c#

What is the easiest way to get my external IP-address in C#?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, the link you provided does not apply.  That question asks about how to get the local IP address.  The OP here asked about the external IP address.

Comment: There might be multiple layers of NAT in operation between you and the machine at the other end of a link - not to mention the possibility of interop layers handling transitions between IP4 and IP6. This makes it very difficult to give your question any meaningful answer. Perhaps, if you edited your question to tell us *why* you think you need this information, someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 7):

There's no built-in way to do it within the framework because it's hard to determine what the external/public IP address is. This of course is assuming your IP is NAT'ed behind some gateway.

One method would be to scrape a site like http://www.whatismyip.org/ using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.webclient.aspx) class.

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string ip = client.DownloadString( "http://www.whatismyip.org" );
Console.Out.WriteLine( ip );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static string GetExternalIP()
{
     using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
         return wc.DownloadString("http://whatismyip.org");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public String getLocalIP()
{
    IPHostEntry host;
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            return ip.ToString();
        }
    }
    return "127.0.0.1";
}
```